# href link doesn't open when left clicking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a little navigation bar on my website and I realized that the links won't open when left clicking on them (Templates/Pricing/sign up /log in).
Anyone has a clue?

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <!-- color, statisch-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse ">
                <!-- button, navbar mit dropmenu wenn bildschirm zu klein-->
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <!-- creates 3 lines in the toggle navigation when screen too little -->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">TAIL
                    <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" id="homeIcon"></span> -->
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="templates.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Templates</a>
                </li> 
                <li class="dropdown"> <a href="pricing.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Pricing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown"> 
                    <a href="register.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Sign Up
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="userIcon"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown"> 
                    <a href="login.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" >Log In 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>          
</nav>
```

Here is the head:

```
<head>
    <title>Built your Website</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

     <!--jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
```

Comment: I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et8usoq3/) with your html and added in the bootstrap CDN and the links "worked" but since I didn't have your files I got 404 errors. Are you also getting 404 errors or is it just that nothing happens when you click them?

Comment: The Tail workss, but templates, pricing, sign up/ log in, won't work 
i don't knwo what you mean, explain please

Comment: Nothing in this code has a visible problem, you must be getting an issue from a different piece of related code.

Comment: also if i right Click and open in new tab, the page opens, but only left cliking is not working

Comment: i editet the question and added more code. please take a look

Comment: @JamieThirkell This question is for Bootstrap 3, so I don't think a link to the V4 docs is going to help too much.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because of the attribute `data-toggle="dropdown"` with the `<a>` tag. When you use this attribute, it prevents the default behavior of the link and tries to open the `dropdown` menu.

For more info check this link : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Remove that attribute from the `<a>` tag and also unnecessary `dropdown`, `dropdown-toggle` and your code should work.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <!-- color, statisch-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse ">
                <!-- button, navbar mit dropmenu wenn bildschirm zu klein-->
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <!-- creates 3 lines in the toggle navigation when screen too little -->
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">TAIL
                    <!-- <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" id="homeIcon"></span> -->
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li>
                    <a href="templates.php">Templates</a>
                </li> 
                <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li> 
                    <a href="register.php">Sign Up
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" id="userIcon"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li> 
                    <a href="login.php">Log In 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" id="logIcon"></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>   
        </div>
    </div>          
</nav>
```

**JSFIDDLE** : https://jsfiddle.net/LLpfvcdu/